# Strip out digits/numeric chars from a mysql string column

Tags: mysql

I have columns in a mysql table that stores names of people as combinations of strings and incremented digits for uniqueness, so I have names stored as so :

```
Patrick, Patrick1, Patrick2, ..... Patrick10, David, David2, .... David5
```

How do I retrieve just the alpha name itself, without the digits? Say I want to group by the distinct names, and count per group, so I get a result resembling the following.

```
name    | frequency
-----------------
Patrick | 10
David   | 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be this:(it doesn't look to good, but it works)

```
SELECT 
  TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM 
    TRIM(TRAILING '1' FROM 
      TRIM(TRAILING '2' FROM 
        TRIM(TRAILING '3' FROM 
          -- ... 
            TRIM(TRAILING '8' FROM 
              TRIM(TRAILING '9' FROM name)))))) AS name
FROM your_table
```

Then you can select with GROUP BY from the result:

```
SELECT name, count(*) AS frequency FROM (
-- previous select
) AS t
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: That'd be OK provided the numbers don't reach as high as 21.

Comment: Whoops! Then the digits should be replaced to a single one and then use TRIM.

Answer (score 0):

I'll have a little think about that, but I would recommend that if you need a distinguishing number, you keep it in a different column. That way, you won't have difficulties of this sort.

Comment: I am not maintaining that table, and I don't have access to the code that populates the columns, hence my request

Comment: You have my deepest sympathy, Olaseni.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a [udf](https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp).

and then try Something like follwing

```
select REGEX_REPLACE(name, [0-9], '') as Name, Count(Name) 
      from tableName  
      Group by Name
```

Comment: I think that's Oracle and PostgreSQL; I can't find it in the MySQL manual.

Comment: A MySQL version of REGEXP_REPLACE is available as a UDF from https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp

Answer (score 0):

You can "chain" the replace command like this (this will remove the digits 0,1,2 in the query). You can expand this for the other digits, but I don't know if this will perform very well on large datasets:

select replace(replace(replace(Name,"0",""),"1",""),"2","") from users;

I would think also, it will be better to do what Brian suggested.

Comment: How do you ensure that only appended digits are removed?

Comment: I was about to say, Volker had cracked it. I think you'll have to create your own stored function to process the name. More information in 12.1.15 of the MySQL Reference Manual if you need it.