# Extracting a section of a larger mysql query to use independantly

Tags: mysql, regex, concatenation

I have the following mysql query in use at the moment, but due to some major re coding being done, i need to take just a small portion of this query to be used on it's own. 
The current query is

```
$sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO FENQUIRY
                (ENREGION, ENNAME, ENCOMP, ENADD1, ENADD2, ENADD3, ENCNTY,
                 ENPCODE, ENCNTRY, ENTEL, ENDATE, ENDATELCON, ENCAT,
                 ENCONSRS, ENADVER, ENTYPE, EN_CUSTOMER_ID)
                SELECT
                    (SELECT region
                         FROM postcode2region
                         WHERE ab.entry_postcode REGEXP
                             CONCAT("^", postcode_prefix, "[:digit:]*")
                         ORDER BY postcode_prefix DESC LIMIT 1
                    ) AS ENREGION,
                    c.ENCONNAME AS ENNAME,
                    IF(ab.entry_company <> "", ab.entry_company,
                         CONCAT(c.ENCONNAME, " - online")) AS ENCOMP,
                    ab.entry_street_address AS ENADD1,
                    ab.entry_suburb AS ENADD2,
                    ab.entry_city AS ENADD3,
                    ab.entry_state AS ENCNTY,
                    ab.entry_postcode AS ENPCODE,
                    cc.countries_name AS ENCNTRY,
                    c.ENCONTEL AS ENTEL,
                    CURDATE() AS ENDATE,
                    CURDATE() AS ENDATELCON,
                    "X" AS ENCAT,
                    1 AS ENCONSRS,
                    "WWW" AS ENADVER,
                    "70" AS ENTYPE,
                    c.ENCON_ID AS EN_CUSTOMER_ID
                FROM FENQCON c
                LEFT JOIN address_book ab
                      ON ab.address_book_id = c.ENCON_ZEN_DEFAULT_ADDRESS_ID
                LEFT JOIN countries cc
                      ON cc.countries_id = ab.entry_country_id
                WHERE c.ENCON_ID = %d
                LIMIT 1',
                $_SESSION['customer_id']);
```

The portion i wish to use is

```
SELECT region FROM postcode2region
    WHERE ab.entry_postcode REGEXP
        CONCAT("^", postcode_prefix, "[:digit:]*")
    ORDER BY postcode_prefix DESC LIMIT 1
```

but if I run that alone it obviously reports that it doesn't know what ab.entry_postcode is, so i tried changing it to

```
SELECT region FROM postcode2region
    WHERE (SELECT entry_postcode FROM address_book REGEXP
        CONCAT("^", postcode_prefix, "[:digit:]*"))
    ORDER BY postcode_prefix DESC LIMIT 1
```

but then i just get an error message of #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REGEXP CONCAT("^", postcode_prefix, "[:digit:]*")) ORDER BY postcode_prefix DESC' at line 1

In short, the query is supposed to look at the postcode stored in field named entry_postcode of the address_book table, take just the leading letters of that postcode, and then fetch the matching data from the region field of the postcode2region table.

I'm sure it should be possible to do it in a single query, but I haven't managed to work it out. If not, I'll do it as two queries.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In case what you need is extracting the prefix of the postcode (the part matching the regex) as part of your query, it's not easy and it's probably better if you do further processing within your code and not using SQL. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3312499/387110) for details on how you could extract the prefix.

Otherwise, I don't know what your tables exactly look like but I'll try anyway. I'll also mention I'm not used to MySQL (but Oracle). The portion of the query which you want to use is:

```
SELECT region
  FROM postcode2region
 WHERE ab.entry_postcode regexp concat("^", postcode_prefix, "[:digit:]*")
 ORDER BY postcode_prefix DESC LIMIT 1
```

You say that you want to get the `region` from the `postcode2region` table where the `postcode_prefix` is the prefix of the `entry_postcode` from the `address_book` table.

If I understand correctly, your query should look something along the lines of this:

```
SELECT region
  FROM postcode2region, (SELECT entry_postcode FROM address_book)
 WHERE entry_postcode regexp concat("^", postcode_prefix, "[:digit:]*")
 ORDER BY postcode_prefix DESC LIMIT 1
```

This should get you the regions with prefixes of any of the postcodes in the address book (limited to 1 row). Is this what you wanted?

Note that in your original query, you were also filtering by `fenqcon.encon_id` but here, there's no filter apart from the `LIMIT 1`.