# How Can I remove the numeric values from mysql column

Tags: mysql

hello I want to remove numeric values from column.

[image]

Please let me know what would be the query to remove all the numeric values from mysql database

**Note:**

**This Note is for those who are marking this question as duplicate**

Please understand the difference. I don't want to "select" the string values from column. I want to completely remove the integer values or numeric values from column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strip out digits/numeric chars from a mysql string column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177974/strip-out-digits-numeric-chars-from-a-mysql-string-column)

Comment: Removing my duplicate suggestion from the comments here since I didn't realize that the numeric value is sitting in the same record as the string. yucko. @jszobody's suggested duplicate is correct. Kind of partial to the `regex_replace` udf suggestion.

Comment: @JNevill no jszobody's  suggested duplicate is not correct. that answer is for the select query. I need the update query. Hope you understand the difference

Comment: You can't translate that answer into an UPDATE query by yourself? It's a basic CRUD operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if it will fix according as follow:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(city_name, '\n', 1), '\n', -1) FROM yourtable;
```

If you're sure, do the following:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET city_name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(city_name, '\n', 1), '\n', -1);
```

Reference: [How to split the name string in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950466/how-to-split-the-name-string-in-mysql)